# Run test insert scripts in before and after Junit testing Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have a Junit test case for testing a method which require some initial data. The data required is not part of the current schema used by my hibernate project. So I cannot use model object to create that insert data. Is there any way to run sql scripts before and after running junit test ?

The Non Hibernate way is the following

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -U user -d db -h host -f file.sql");
```

How to handle this using hibernate ?

Comment: Might want to look at [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) and [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html). Also you might want to look at [this](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/understaning-junit-method-order-execution/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running native sql query using the hibernate api

```
Query persistableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("QUERY"); 
persistableQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The @Sql annotation is my first option.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql)
Haven't tried it, but since you are using Spring, you can also use ScriptUtils in your @Before method:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new ClassPathResource("test_db.sql"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also nice library called [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) that allows to set database to known state before and after junit tests.